# Shape uncertainty of a 3D point cloud

Tags: regression, information-theory, uncertainty, point-estimation, geometry

Given a point cloud of a 3D object,

how to calculate the shape uncertainty in this discrete sample set?

and what factors maximize or minimize this uncertainty?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "shape uncertainty."  Some indication of how this point cloud was obtained and measured would be helpful.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the comment. The point cloud is captured by scanning the surface of a 3D object. To extract high level information, we need to process this raw geometry geometry based on continuous surface representations. However, since any discrete sampling provides only incomplete information about the underlying object, the reconstructed surfaces from this point cloud may not uniquely demonstrate the original data.

Comment: @whuber, the discrete sampling provides spatial information only at a finite number of points. This introduces uncertainty, since the course of the surface in between sample points is unknown and needs to be inferred from the sample set.

Comment: This uncertainty information is useful because it helps to identify the minimal number of points required to correctly represent a surface with a specific orientation and curvature.